# Encryption in Smart GWT

Tags: smartgwt

we are using smart GWT as our front end. i need to do password encrytion in this.Before smart GWT we were using GWT Ext and the encryption was done using gwt-crypto.jar.Which jar is needed to do encrytion in smart GWT.

Thanks in advance,
Rima Desai

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use gwt-crypto all the same? As it is not "visual", it will not interfere with the DOM/CSS so SmartGWT should not care.

Comment: [code] com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
 at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(PKCS7Padding.java:68)
 at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.java:295)
 at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.client.TripleDesCipher.decrypt(TripleDesCipher.java:55)
 at com.nextenders.client.util.other.EncryptionUtil.decrypt(EncryptionUtil.java:50)at com.nextenders.client.ui.triad.view.EditUserPanel.setFormData(EditUserPanel.java:132)